# ios-charts - Multiple Value selected methods for chart selections

Tags: swift2, ios9, ios-charts

I am using [ios-charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts) for plotting charts in my view controller. I have 3 charts in the view where I want to show the 2nd chart based on value selection of 1st chart and same I want to show the 3rd chart based on value selection of 2nd chart, in a sequence.

Showing 2nd chart based on value selection of 1st chart was easy due to chart value selected method i.e

```
func chartValueSelected(chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, highlight: ChartHighlight) {
}
```

I am not able to use same method for 2nd to 3rd Chart. I need help to solve this.
I am trying this to show the 2nd chart on the selection of value from 1st chart.

```
// A delegate method from data model
func dataDidLoad(controller: DataModel) {
        var chartArray:[PFObject] = [PFObject]()

        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMM"
        dataDict = [:]
        for element in chartArray {
            let data = od["Data1"] as! String

            if self.dataDict.indexForKey(data) != nil {
                self.dataDict[value]! += 1.0
            }else{
                self.dateDict.updateValue(1.0, forKey: data1.desc)
            }
        }
        let dataPointArray = Array(dataDict.keys)
        let valuesArray = Array(dataDict.values)
        pieChartView.data = nil
        setChart1(dataPointArray, values: valuesArray)
    }

// This method sets the first chart and working fine
func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {
    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
    var label = ""
    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {

        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        label += "\(dataPoints[i]) "
    }

    let pieChartDataSet = PieChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: label)
    let pieChartData = PieChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSet: pieChartDataSet)
    pieChartView.data = pieChartData
    pieChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: NSTimeInterval(5))
    var colors: [UIColor] = []

    for _ in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let red = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
        let green = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
        let blue = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))

        let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red/255), green: CGFloat(green/255), blue: CGFloat(blue/255), alpha: 1)
        colors.append(color)
    }  
    pieChartDataSet.colors = colors  
}

// This menthod is the delegate method from ios chart liberary. And gets triggered when any data selected from chart1
func chartValueSelected(chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, highlight: ChartHighlight) {

    data2Dict = [:]
    for element in chart2Array {
        let data2 = od["Data2"] as! String

        if self.data2Dict.indexForKey(data2) != nil {
            self.data2Dict[data2]! += 1.0
        }else{
            self.data2Dict.updateValue(1.0, forKey: data2)
        }
    }

    let valuesArray = Array(data2Dict.values)
    let dPointArray = Array(data2Dict.keys)
    setChart2(dPointArray, values: valuesArray)
}

// This method sets the 2nd chart and working fine
func setChart2(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {
    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
    var label = ""
    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {

        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        label += "\(dataPoints[i]) "
    }

    let pieChartDataSet = PieChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: label)
    let pieChartData = PieChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSet: pieChartDataSet)
    pieChartView.data = pieChartData
    pieChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: NSTimeInterval(5))
    var colors: [UIColor] = []

    for _ in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let red = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
        let green = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
        let blue = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))

        let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red/255), green: CGFloat(green/255), blue: CGFloat(blue/255), alpha: 1)
        colors.append(color)
    }  
    pieChartDataSet.colors = colors  
}
```

Since the data is dynamic and changes for 2nd and third chart based on selection of data from previous chart, I can not use same event to trigger 2nd and 3rd chart at same time.

Comment: Show us the code you are using to show the second chart. Also, why can't you just use the same event from the second chart to show the third?

Comment: Thank you for response, I have updated the question with relevant details. Let me know in case any more input required.

Comment: Looking better! I see your event handler code,  but I don't yet see where the event handler is hooked up to chart 1's change event.

Comment: I believe that happens by default since the event handler is delegate method, which means when chart 1's value select event happens it gets triggered automatically.

Comment: So does the same handler get called by Chart 2 and 3 but you aren't sure how to code your handler to work when called by multiple charts or are you saying that it doesn't get called?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what is happening here. When I Select Values from chart one chartValueSelected method gets called and execute the print statement if i put one there, but when i select value from chart 2 it doesn't print the statement. Hence I am assuming it isn't getting called.

Comment: I believe it's the view controller's logic to pass data among the 3 charts. when you interact witch each chart, delegate the event handling to view controller, and let view controller determine which chart should be updated.

Comment: also if your chart #1 and chart #2 are not same class, chartValueSelected will never be called by chart #2. Reconsider your design and the delegate first